# prevent page caching with Rails and Passenger in Development Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

I am running Rails 3 and Passenger 2 and I don't know why but my page is still cached despite having this configuration (in one of my virtual hosts):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName railstut.dev
    ServerAlias *.railstut.dev
    DocumentRoot "/home/ygamretuta/dev/railstut/public/"
    RailsEnv "development"

    <Directory "/home/ygamretuta/dev/railstut/">
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried it in Firefox with the browser cache disabled (via web developer plugin) so I don't think there's a problem with the browser cache. I always need to restart the server to see the changes made (even with some minor changes like replacing a text).

What could be the problem?

**EDIT**
Passenger seems to be setting the environment to production despite there being a RailsEnv config option.

**EDIT**
Passenger runs on production environment as seen on some of my pages accessing the DB. It looks for the database name configured in the production section in the database.yml file.

Comment: Although "development" works fine for me locally it's worth a shot to try development without the quotes. Also which version of passenger 2 are you running? Could you try upgrading to the latest passenger2 (or 3 even)

Comment: latest version in the 2.x line, just installed it last week. I also tried the "development" with no quotes...to no avail :(

Comment: The weird thing is when I use the server packaged with Rails, I get a "development" when I enter Rails.env in the rails console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://groups.google.com/group/phusion-passenger/browse_thread/thread/ddb9dbbad0bfe679

Answer (score 0):

If you have existing file cache page cache entries, they will supercede the dynamic request even after restarting.  You should clear your tmp or cache directories if you have ever used the file store for caching.

Comment: I will look into this but do you know how I can force Passenger to see the rails environment as development? Because when I go to some pages fetching data from a DB, it fetches data from the production database server with the above configuration